# Excel VBA to Email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, paste

I am trying to creat a macro that takes a table from excel and pastes it into an email and sends. I can do this up but the table stays as a table and I want to paste special image. I have tried lots of different approaches and lots of googling but to no avail. Please help... thanks.

The code so far

```
TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)"  'Paste:=2
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain the approaches you have tried so that others don't make the same mistake when trying to help or maybe spot a mistake in your approach

Comment: See http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3679231/How-to-Create-Great-HTML-Emails-with-CSS.htm. Images have to be in a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to copy the selected table as a bitmap picture then you can use standard paste command to paste the table as a pticture.

```
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
```